# Dashed line VTK C++

Tags: c++, qt, vtk

I am new to vtk and i am trying to draw dash line i used that code and still its solid

```
double x1 = 0.0;
double y1 = 0.0;
double x2 = 1.0;
double y2 = 1.0;
linesource->SetPoint1(x1, y1, 0.0);
linesource->SetPoint2(x2, y2, 0.0);
linesource->Update();
linemapper->SetInputConnection(linesource->GetOutputPort());
lineactor->SetMapper(linemapper);
lineactor->GetProperty()->SetColor(1.0, 0.0, 0.0); // Set line color to red
renderer->AddActor(lineactor);
vtkProperty* lineProperty = lineactor->GetProperty();
lineProperty->SetLineStipplePattern(0xf0f0);
lineProperty->SetLineStippleRepeatFactor(5);
```